# The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send on

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices

I have a windows Service routine which is written in [C#].Net using VS 2010 which hits the DB once a day and if there are any records which need to be addressed. These record owners will be sent an email through the Exchange server.
For the first few records the emails are sent fine but after may be 4rth or 5th Email I get an error as show

```
Service failed at :System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.Emit(HttpWebRequest& request)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(HttpWebRequest& request)
```

If I debug the routine with break points it works fine. But when I run it without any break points I get the above error.
Here is the snippet of code in which my routine sends emails:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
lock (service)
{
   if (service == null)
      throw new Exception("service is null");
   service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(data[0], data[1]);
   service.Url = new Uri("https://owa.CompanyName.com/ews/exchange.asmx");
   service.Timeout = 1200000;
   EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(service);
   if (message == null)
       throw new Exception("message is null");
       message.Subject = "Test Email";
       message.Body = "This is a Test EMail Please use the below link to update ";

//message.ToRecipients.Add(docList[0].CreatorEmailID);
       message.ToRecipients.Add("EmailID@gmail.com");
       for (int j = 0; j < emailList.Count; j++)
       {
          message.CcRecipients.Add("EmailID@gmail.com”);
       }
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
       ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ignoreCertCallback;
       try
       {
        message.Send();
       }
       finally
       {
       ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback -= ignoreCertCallback;
       }
}
```

I have used Microsoft Exchange WebService  as a web reference here.
I tried googling it but it didn’t really help me. I would be really happy if someone can help me on this issue.

Comment: why are you `lock()`ing on the object you've just created in the same scope?

Comment: Well I was just using during the test. to check if any email service is accessing it during the operation. I can remove it.

Comment: Well, no. My point is that that lock doesn't do what you probably think it does. Which to me means your sample code is missing important details about how the service object is initialized. Really the question is: are you creating new service object for every message sent or you keep a static copy (which is why there would a lock)?

Comment: Ok. Yes,I create a new service object for every message to be sent.

Comment: Here is a snippet of code which calls the email object: public bool PurgeData(int startDay,int endDay) { foreach (Doc doc in listData[i]) { if (!doc.SupervisorEmailID.Equals(string.Empty) && !doc.SupervisorEmailID.Equals(null)) { mailValue = true; supervisorId.Add(doc.SupervisorEmailID.Trim()); } else { mailValue = false; } } if (mailValue) { returnValue = sendmail(i, (listData[i] as List<Doc>)[0].CreatorEmailID, supervisorId); }

Answer (score 2):

My guess:

Exchange doesn't like the number of connections you are opening in a short amount of time and thinks it's under attack and subsequently blocking you from making more connections.

The first thing I would do is recode that "service".  You don't want to instantiate a new one for each message.  Just reuse the existing object.  Also, send your messages one at a time to it.

Alternatively, speak with your Exchange administrator to see if they know how to reconfigure exchange to let your spam, I mean very important messages, through.. ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will re-code my Emailmessage object using the same Exchange service object as you said and get back to you.

Comment: Hey Chris, I have followed you suggestion to create only one "Exchnage service" object and send messages one at a time. I got the same errors as I mentioned above!

Comment: @AAK: you need to speak with your exchange administrator.  Exchange has it rate limited.

Comment: I will check with my Exhchange Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see...

Works under debugger with breakpoints, doesn't work without.

Maybe you need to rate limit yourself.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry but I didn't get you.

Comment: Something like Sleep(2000) in between each message.

Comment: I have done a System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); for each message even then I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem,but my code is correct under debugger on localhost.When I uploaded my app, and someone wants to send email this error is appeared.
**Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.**

```
try
        {
            string txtBody = "";
            string emailUser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailAuthUser"];
            string emailPass = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailAuthPass"];
            string mailServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailServer"];

            txtBody = "<b>" + ("موضوع:" + "  " + emailmod.Subject + "</b>" + "<br/><br/><b>" + "ارسال کننده: </b>" + emailmod.SenderEmail + "<br/><br/><b>" + "پیام: </b>" + emailmod.Message + "<br/><br/>" + emailmod.PagePath);

            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CertificateValidationCallBack;
            ExchangeService exservice = new ExchangeService();
            AutodiscoverService auservice = new AutodiscoverService(mailServer);
            if (auservice.ServerInfo != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    exservice.AutodiscoverUrl(emailUser);
                }
                catch (AutodiscoverRemoteException ex)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("Exception thrown: " + ex.Error.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                exservice.Url = new Uri("https://" + "outlook.apornak.com" + "/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
            }
            exservice.UseDefaultCredentials = true;


            if (exservice.ServerInfo == null)
            {
                exservice.Credentials = new WebCredentials(emailUser, emailPass);
            }

            EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(exservice);
            message.Subject = "اعلام ایرادات و پیشنهادات";
            message.Body = Resources.Message.AdvMailTemplate.Replace("#$Body$#", txtBody);
            message.ToRecipients.Add("support@apornak.com");
            message.From = "اعلام ایرادات و پیشنهادات";
            message.ReplyTo.Add( emailmod.SenderEmail);
            message.Save();

            message.SendAndSaveCopy();
            return Json(true);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            { return Json(false); }
            throw;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally if there is a certificate problem use this where you are making the resquest,

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);

...and

public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            return true;
        }

Answer (score 0):

in IIS, the ssl certificate was unselected. Perhaps was deleted by Fiddler settings...
I recreated the ssl certificate with makecert command and eureka!
I had this error when calling a web service on https://

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please fix the capitalization and grammar. Try to refrain from using improper English.